# Change div color using multiple radio buttons and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to use radio buttons to change the background color of my div tag. I would like to use more than more condition. E.g., if button A is clicked and button B is clicked then make the color green.
This is what I have so far.

```
<div id="CLWarn">Warning Colour </div>
<input type="radio" name="IM" id="IM" value="1" onclick="A(this)"/>
<input type="radio" name="PB" id="PB" value="1" onclick="B(this)"/>

function A(chk) {
if(chk.checked == true) {
function B(chk) {
if(chk.checked == true) {   
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("CLWarn").style.backgroundColor="Green";
document.getElementById("CLWarn").style.lineHeight=1.8;})
}}
}}
```

It works if I'm only using one condition (just clicking one button and only having the one function, but I don't know how to add another condition to my function.

Comment: You're missing a good amount of closing braces here. Are you sure this works?

Comment: Two inputs with the same ID?

Comment: Are you sure you need radio buttons? Only one radio can be selected with same name.

Comment: I think that you need check button instead readio buttons.

Comment: These are two groups of 4 radio buttons,

Comment: Around `$(document).ready(function{ /* ... */ })` you missed a semicolon `;` after the parenthesis. Check console for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you try to do something like this:

```js
function A(chk) {
    if ( document.getElementById("IM1").checked && document.getElementById("IM2").checked ) {
        document.getElementById("CLWarn").style.backgroundColor="Green";
        document.getElementById("CLWarn").style.lineHeight=1.8;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="CLWarn">Warning Colour </div>
<input type="radio" name="IM1" id="IM1" value="1" onclick="A(this)"/>
<input type="radio" name="IM2" id="IM2" value="1" onclick="A(this)"/>
```

Notice that there are different `name`s for the radio buttons to allow multiple selection. And the `id`s are also unique according to some good practices.

Answer (score 1):

Although jquery hasn't been tagged, as the OP has used it in his code, here is a jquery solution:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
      if ($('#IM').is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#PB').is(':checked')) {
          alert('green');
        } else {
          alert('blue');
        } 
        } else {
          alert('red');
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="IM" id="IM" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="PB" id="PB" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, your radio buttons have the same 'Name' value, meaning only one can be checked at a time.

If I understand correctly, you can achieve what you want using something like the following:

```js
function changeColour(element) {
  var div = document.getElementById('CLWarn');
  if (element.id == 'a' && element.checked) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else if (element.id == 'b' && element.checked) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="CLWarn">Warning Colour</div>
<input type="radio" name="IM" id="a" value="1" onchange="changeColour(this)" />
<input type="radio" name="IM" id="b" value="1" onchange="changeColour(this)" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes is was a mistake when I wrote the original questions about the names. I've now edited it. Thanks you again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use checkbox instead radio:

```
<div id="CLWarn">Warning Colour </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="IM1" id="IM1" class="chk" />
<input type="checkbox" name="IM2" id="IM2" class="chk" />
```

and use jquery to archieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".chk").change(function(){
       var im1 = $("#IM1");
       var im2 = $("#IM1");

       if ($("#IM1").is(':checked') &&  $("#IM2").is(':checked')){
           $("#CLWarn").css("background-color", "green");
           $("#CLWarn").css("line-height", "1.8rem");
       }       
   })
})
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/khbtyrL9/)

Addictionally you can puy all your css in a separate class and set with addClass

```
 $("#CLWarn").addClass("myClass");
```